# Уточняющий или поясняющий оборот?

Tags: грамматика, семантика

Даны предложения:

> (2) Их лепестки, широкие и плоские или с завёрнутыми внутрь краями и
> свёрнутые в узенькие иглы-трубочки, могут быть разных цветов.

> (5) Георгины соответствовали представлениям русского человека о красивом
> цветке, большом и ярком.

I. Хочется узнать, чем являются данные определительные обороты. Уточняющими или поясняющими оборотами? Или их [обороты] нельзя к отнести оным? тогда как они называются?

Из теории предполагаю:

**Уточняющий оборот** (**УО**) - это переход из более широкого понятия к узкому. *УО должен стоять после уточняемого слова* - т.е. если "УО" стоит не после уточняемого, то оно относится к другому слову и назвать "УО" УО нельзя? То есть уточняющим оборотом определение в (2) предложении нельзя назвать, из-за того что уточняемое "их" отделено от УО?

**Поясняющий оборот (ПО)** - это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами, другое название. Могут ли данные обороты быть поясняющими? Может ли ПО стоять не после уточняемого?

II.(2) ***Их лепестки, только широкие и плоские или с завёрнутыми внутрь краями и свёрнутые в узенькие иглы-трубочки, могут быть разных цветов*** - в таком контексте ограничивается определение "их", т.е. не все лепестки могут быть разных цветов, а только "широкие и..."? Тогда это уточняющий оборот?

(2.1) ***Их лепестки (они широкие и плоские) могут быть разных цветов...*** - в таком контексте говорится, что все лепестки данного растения широкие и плоские и все они могут быть разных цветов?

(5) ***Георгины соответствовали представлениям русского человека о красивом цветке, большом и ярком*** - в таком контексте УО невозможен? То есть нельзя понять, что красивый - это большой и яркий.

(5.1) ***Георгины соответствовали представлениям русского человека о красивом цветке, то есть большом и ярком*** - в данном контексте ПО тоже невозможен, т.к. отдален от поясняемого?

Чем тогда все же являются данные обороты?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146105/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере определительный оборот, стоящий после существительного.

Ср. Грянул грязный городской ливень, **перемешанный с пылью** (Б. Паст.); Антон Павлович Чехов, **пересекавший еще на лошадях в конце прошлого века Сибирь в поездке на Сахалин,** проскучал до самого Енисея (Расп.); Мастер, **дремавший на травке,** встал навстречу и кивнул (Зал.); В жесткой траве, п**охожей на шерсть козы,** цвели меж низких полыней лиловые низкие цветки (Цвет.); Пыль, **розовая от блеска молний,** неслась по земле (Пауст.); Рыхлые тучи, н**апитанные темной водой**, низко неслись над морем (Пауст.)

Во втором примере нераспространенные определения обособляются, т.к. имеют пояснительно-конкретизирующее значение.

Ср.: Я часто находил у себя записки, **короткие и тревожные** (Ч.); Утром он разворачивает газету, местную (Сол.); Распахиваю в ночь, черную, звездную, соррентийскую, **створку окна** (Цвет.).

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118).

Ср. также примеры из справочника [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108).